# IP whitelist for remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, ip, firewall, whitelist

I have a big list of IP ranges which I want to import to windows firewall. It is a pain to import them one by one.

Is there any automatic way to achieve that? A script that can create rules for port with large number of IPs? I hold them in a file.
And what about performance of a large IP based rule?

Answer (score 1):

## Export rules, edit, then import

You could export the rules as a CSV or JSON file, edit them to include your new IP ranges, then import the rules back into the WIndows Firewall.

You may find these scripts useful:

[Powershell scripts to export and import firewall rules in CSV or JSON format](https://github.com/MScholtes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/ExportImportFirewallRules)

Answer (score 0):

You can add IP range via Scope tab:

1. Open the rule you created in Windows Firewall
2. Click on the **Scope** tab.
3. For remote IP addresses, click **Add**.
4. Click **This IP address range**.
5. For the first range, From: **** To:**** and click **OK**.
6. Click OK one last time to save your rule.

You can refer to this Microsoft document:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesteve/2017/06/26/allowing-rdp-access-to-only-certain-ips/

Comment: I know this option. But it is a pain to add them like that, cause I have a very large list. Also windows firewall has a limit of IP entries per rule. I'm looking for something that can read the IPs from a file and sort of automate this process